# SQL Database GUI written in Python

Tags: python, sql, database, user-interface, client

I've been ripping my face off trying to find a SQL database GUI client that is written in Python. I know that a particular project already exists and I can only remember that it was written in Python (and had a FOSS licence).

I know there are many questions (without the Python-specific requirement) floating around SO - I've read a lot of them and checked all links to no avail. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

[crunchyfrog](http://code.google.com/p/crunchyfrog/)